# Slow Excel File with many sheets and macros

Tags: vba, performance, crash

I have a main excel file, which currently holds 156 worksheets and more than 30 vba modules. Each worksheet has hundreds and maybe thousands of cells with formulas and many of them speaks to some other worksheets. And this file is being used by 3 individuals on server time to time.

As one can imagine, file started to give errors, started to crash and working on it became a burden.

I am open to any suggestion to make it fast again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here which would have a knock-on effect on the speed.

Most of the things that you listed would cause problems with the exception of the VBA modules.   Thirty is really nothing but, as regarding the other stuff...

I have found that formulae is the worst culprit for creating speed issues and for causing errors.   There's a limit to the number of formulae one can have before things start to go wrong but even before reaching that limit the spreadsheet slows down horrendously and can become unusable.

Having a spreadsheet open across a network is also a bit of a nightmare and is something that I would try to avoid if I could.

In short, the whole thing needs to be redesigned because 156 worksheets is rather a lot especially if each sheet has thousands of formulae.    The whole thing needs to be redesigned and another tool, a database perhaps, needs to be used especially as it's shared between more than one person.

Shorter still:  it's too big and you're at breaking point.